# Loading and using .NET assembly in SWI Prolog

Tags: c#, .net, swi-prolog

I'm looking for a way to use custom .NET classes (written in C#) from SWI Prolog. I've already checked the orignal solution proposed on [SWI-Prolog pages](http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.html), however it seems to be an interface to call Prolog predicates from C#.

I've also checked [Prolog.NET](http://prolog.hodroj.net/documentation.html), which seems to exactly fit my needs with its `using('System.Collections')` or `assembly('MyMath.dll')` predicates. The problem, however, is, that I haven't found a way to integrate it with SWI-Prolog, which is a tool I'm to use.

The last possible solution was to use [SwiCLI](https://code.google.com/p/opensim4opencog/wiki/SwiCLI), but the interface doesn't seem very good and I'd probably have to call C# procedures to manually load my assembly, as there doesn't seem to be a way to load assemblies directly from Prolog.

Is there another way you'd recommend? Thanks!

Comment: Read this: [SWI-Prolog 2-Way interface to .NET/Mono](http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/NetMono.html)

Comment: Thanks. That's actually about the SwiCLI module. I've had some troubles running it (on Win8 and 64bit SWI Prolog) but it seems to be the answer.

Comment: @user2742898 What troubles did you have running it on Win8 with 64-bit SWI-Prolog?  Were you able to get those problems resolved?  I'm thinking of using that same module for some C# to SWI-Prolog and SWI-Prolog to C# work.